# Typescript. Define generic <T> keys as string

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, typescript-typings

I want to get some object and modify it by keys as strings and return object.

```
const useInputs = <T extends Record<string, string>>(defaultValue: T) => {
    const [inputsData, setInputsData] = useState<T>(defaultValue)

    type UpdateFunction = (key: string) => (el: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
    const updateData: UpdateFunction = key => el => {
        const newInputsData = {...inputsData}
        newInputsData[key] = el.target.value
        setInputsData(newInputsData)
    }

    return { inputsData, updateData }
}
```

but I have error on `newInputsData[key] = el.target.value`
"Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.ts(2536)"

How I can fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes about because the generic type `T` may be instantiated with any type that extends `Record<string, string>`.

Consider the type

```
interface Inputs {x: string; y: string}
```

While `Inputs` extends `Record<string, string>`, it would be completely unsafe to allow indexing into it with arbitrary strings.

In other words, we wouldn't want the following

```
const i: Inputs = {x: "A", y: "B"};
const [inputs, setInputs] = useInputs(i);
setInputs("name")(event);
```

because `Inputs` doesn't have a `name` property.

Therefore, your inner type, `UpdateFunction`, must take an argument that is a valid key of the whatever type `T` is instantiated with for any instantiation. Such a type is written `keyof T` as in `(key: keyof T) => (el: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void`.

Putting it together it should look like this

```
const useInputs = <T extends Record<string, string>>(defaultValue: T) => {
    const [inputsData, setInputsData] = useState<T>(defaultValue);

    type UpdateFunction = (key: keyof T) => (el: {target: {value: T[keyof T]}}) => void;
    const updateData: UpdateFunction = key => el => {
        const newInputsData = {...inputsData};
        newInputsData[key] = el.target.value;
        setInputsData(newInputsData)
    };

    return [inputsData, updateData] as const;
};
```

Note the adjustment in the return value of the outer function which allows for the conventional use of your hook.

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useInputs(...);
```

as opposed to the unorthodox

```
const {inputsData, updateData} = useInputs(...);
```

Further, note that in order to make the above typecheck, we've also had to adjust the type of the second parameter, `el`, which provides the value to update the property with from `React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>` to `{target: {value: T[keyof T]}}` for the same reason discussed above, the generic `T` may be instantiated with properties whose *values* are subtypes of `string` such as `"despair"` and `"elation"`.

Alternatives include using a more precise type for `el` such as

```
Omit<React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>, "target"> & {
  target: { value: T[keyof T] };
}
```

Moving changing *how* `useInput` is generic, from the type of the entire input object, to the just the property keys of that object.

```
const useInputs = <K extends string>(defaultValue: Record<K, string>) => {
  const [inputsData, setInputsData] = useState(defaultValue);

  type UpdateFunction = (
    key: K
  ) => (el: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  const updateData: UpdateFunction = key => el => {
    const newInputsData = { ...inputsData };
    newInputsData[key] = el.target.value;
    setInputsData(newInputsData);
  };

  return [inputsData, updateData] as const;
};
```

I prefer this last, because `HTMLInputElement`'s `value` is always a `string`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You are absolutely right about conventional use [] instead of {} as return value. 

But `(key: keyof T)` doesn't help. I have an error in the same place: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'`

I have no idea why its happen because I use Record<string,string>.

Comment: @PetrTcoi, I see the issue. I've updated with a version that type checks and some alternatives

Comment: Oh... `{target: {value: T[keyof T]}}` works! You saved me. Thank you

Comment: @PetrTcoi yeah. There are a few different approaches. My preference is actually the last one, which I added at the end of the answer.

Comment: @PetrTcoi Care to accept this if it worked for you?

Comment: Sorry. Missed the question... What do you mean?

Comment: If you feel this answers your question fully and adequately, you can choose to mark it as accepted. Absolutely don't if you would like to wait and see but, I would be happy to address any feedback and improve this answer as well.